# Reusing same session from asp.net aspx page to ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I am trying to call an ashx handler from asp.net page and retrieve xml data from handler.

```
  var url = "http://localhost/Settings/MyHandler.ashx?errors=false";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stm = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stm))
                {
                    var data= sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, due to the nature of asp.net creating new session for each webrequest, i am not able to reuse the same session from asp.net page to ashx handler.

Both files are from same project.

How can i reuse the same session from asp.net to ashx handler.?

Please note: i already have marked my handler to implement IRequireSessionState,  so it has session. My issue is that aspx page and ashx handler have two different sessions.. Everytime when i invoke handler it creates a new session. But instead i have to reuse the same session of aspx page inside my handler, meaning i have to execute handler in the same request context of my page.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify that your .ashx class uses the IRequiresSessionState interface e.g.

```
public class myClass : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

{

}

Then you should be able to get access to the current session values via `HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: my handler already implements IRequireSessionState, that does n't solve my problem as everytime when i invoke the handler it creates new session